# Laravel validation exists where NOT

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Based on the [documentations](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists). Exists can have 4 parameters:

```
exists:table,id,where,0
```

The question is, What if I wanted it to be where is not. Like where is not 0.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array(
        'groups' => $groups
    ),
    array(
        'groups' => 'required|exists:groups,jid,parent,!=,0'
    )
);
```

Comment: You can use custom validation. http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I'm trying to look into it. Thanks again @Anam. Kinda new to php though.

Comment: @Anam I seem to not understand how the custom validation works, and how to implement it with exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Validator::extend('not_exists', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return DB::table($parameters[0])
        ->where($parameters[1], '=', $value)
        ->andWhere($parameters[2], '<>', $value)
        ->count()<1;
});
```

Comment: total overkill look below

Answer (score 54):

You can use `unique`

**Example**

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

*In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.*

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: This is basically the same as the accepted answer, except it comes ready to go with Laravel, and it also has the added benefit of being abel to define an ignored id, which is especially helpful on updates.

Comment: It's disappointing when the best answers aren't the accepted answers.   Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

With Laravel 5.2 or later you can prepend the values to be checked against with a `!`:

```
'groups' => 'required|exists:groups,jid,parent,!0'
```

The same login goes for `unique`, only you need the extra parameters:

```
'groups' => 'required|unique:groups,jid,NULL,id,parent,!0'
```

Comment: It goes like: exists: (tablename),(columnname)... and then i am lost. Can you explain? Official docs did not help me on this matter.

Comment: If you use the Laravel Degubar package, you can actually check which queries are triggered in each request so you can see what your validation rules are doing with the database. That said, the exist rule is well covered in the docs: `exists:(table name),(column name),[(column name of additional query), (value of column for additional query with optional !)]`

Comment: This is weird, what if it were a string field that had a value which literally begins with `!`?

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking for 'not 0', but for reference sake, you can use `NOT_NULL`, as in:

```
'groups' => 'required|exists:groups,jid,parent,NOT_NULL'
```

It's not listed in the docs right now, but [here is the discussion about it (see very last post)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3087)

Answer (score 0):

A custom validator is here

```
Validator::extend('not_exists', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    $table = array_shift($parameters);
    $db    = \DB::table($table);

    foreach ($parameters as $parameter)
    {
        $check = explode(';', $parameter);
        $col   = array_shift($check);
        $value = array_get($check, 0, array_get($validator->getData(), $col, false));

        $db->where($col, $value);
    }

    return $db->count() < 1;
});
```

Example usage:

```
not_exists:model_has_roles,role_id,model_type;App\User,model_id
```

You can pass default value like this:

```
model_type;App\User
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try `<> 0` ,that's the **SQL** for not equal