# require_without and require_unless for same field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 field `'account_name','billable_option'` and `'billable_option_yes'`

`'billable_option'` is required if `'billable_option_yes'` is not filled and `'billable_option_yes'` is required if `'billable_option'` is not filled

and I want to check both field is not required if `'account_name'` value is `0`

I want to combine the validation `required_unless:account_name,0`

```
$this->validate($request,[
   'billable_option' => 'required_without:billable_option_yes',
   'billable_option_yes' =>'required_without:billable_option',
],$messages);
```

Comment: make your own validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785473/laravel-validation-exists-where-not

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check first the value of account_name and based on that value you can validate further,
Here laravel provides `required_unless` validation to check for this field is required if that is null,

```
if($request->account_name != "0"){
  $this->validate($request,[
   'billable_option' => 'required_unless:billable_option_yes,null',
   'billable_option_yes' =>'required_unless:billable_option,null',
  ],$messages);
}
```

or you can do like this,

```
$this->validate($request,[
   'billable_option' => 'required_if:account_name,==,0|required_unless:billable_option_yes,null',
   'billable_option_yes' =>'required_if:account_name,==,0|required_unless:billable_option,null',
  ],$messages);
```

Hope it helps you.