# Laravel 8 UNIQUE composite key validation

Tags: laravel

In the database, I have a unique index on two columns like

```
`external_id`, `some_id`
```

I believe validating user input should not be a problem for this unique key.

Somehow I still have not found the proper solution

This is what I am doing now, but it looks overkill for this, supposed to be a simple task

```
    $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($request) {

        $some_id = $request->input('some_id');
        $external_id = $request->input('external_id');

        if ($some_id && $external_id) {
            $exists = MyModel::where([
                ['some_id', '=', $some_id],
                ['external_id', '=', $external_id]
            ])->exists();

            if ($exists) {
                $validator->errors()->add('external_id', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
            }
        }
    });
```

Can this be simplified with some built-in validation like exclude_if/unless... etc ?

Comment: `'data.external_id' => ['required', 'unique:servers,external_id, '.$this->external_id], 'data.some_id' => ['required', 'unique:servers,some_id, '.$this->some_id]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after hours of searching and trying and failing I found something

```
'external_id' => "nullable|numeric|min:1|unique:menus,external_id,NULL,id,some_id,$some_id"
                                        | where it searches      | ????? | AND some_id={id}
```

In the rule above, only rows with a some_id of {id} would be included in the unique check.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717913/2641425

Also (modified original documentation text):
"... let's add a query condition that scopes the query to only search records that have a some_id column value of {id}"

```
'external_id' => Rule::unique('table')->where(function ($query) use ($model) {
            return $query->where([
                ['some_id', '=', $model->some_id],
                ['id', '<>', $model->id]
            ]);
        })
```